# start camera without asking for result

Tags: java, android, android-intent, camera

I am looking for an intent to start the camera application without asking for a result.

the only thing i found yet is Camera.ACTION_NEW_PICTURE but this only shoots a photo, I want to display the usual camera app, just without wanting a result from it!

Is there any way to do so?

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

this is basically the relevant code, as this app provides an extension for DashClock, which uses a service and this might be just a wrapper for a pending intent. However, this code causes to infinitely let the camera take pictures on pressing "shoot" and on accept or return button it crashes.

Comment: Just call `startActivity` instead of `startActivityForResult`

Comment: app crashes with runtimeexception after "accepting the shot"..

Comment: @Aeefire Post the relevant code.

Comment: added the code and more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, try this one:

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivity(cameraIntent);
```

Comment: this is, what causes the camera app to go into an infinite loop and crash it on pressing accept or return.